# Pushing to multidimensional objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 arrays and I'd like to create a multidimensional array for each shop.
In the result, the value for "fruit" and "vegetable" is not the sum of each, the result is the total of points (sum of each fruit or vegetable * score of each)

```
var myArray = [{
                shop: "shop1",
                item1: "my apple 0",
                item2: "my carrot 1",
            }, {
                shop: "shop1",
                item1: "my apple 0",
                item2: "my carrot 1",
            }, {
                shop: "shop1",
                item1: "my apple 1",
                item2: "my carrot 0",
            },
            {
                shop: "shop2",
                item1: "my apple 1",
                item2: "my carrot 1",
            }, {
                shop: "shop2",
                item1: "my apple 1",
                item2: "my carrot 0",
            }, {
                shop: "shop2",
                item1: "my apple 0",
                item2: "my carrot 1",
            }
        ];

        var MyArrayDefinition = [{
                item: "my apple 0",
                color: "red",
                group: "fruit",
                score: 0
            }, {
                item: "my carrot 1",
                color: "orange",
                group: "vegetable",
                score: 1
            },
            {
                item: "my apple 1",
                color: "red",
                group: "fruit",
                score: 1
            }, {
                item: "my carrot 0",
                color: "orange",
                group: "vegetable",
                score: 0
            }
        ]
```

This is my function

```
const count = myArray
            .reduce((a, o) => a.concat(Object.values(o)), [])
            .reduce((c, v) => ({ ...c,
                [v]: (c[v] || 0) + 1
            }), {});

        const list = Object.entries(count)
            // map to {type, count}
            .map(([item, number]) => ({
                item,
                number
            }));

        const indices = MyArrayDefinition.map((e) => e.item);
        const combinaison = list.map(e => Object.assign(e, MyArrayDefinition[indices.indexOf(e.item)]));

        var result = _.map(combinaison, function(elt) {
            return ({
                item: elt.question,
                group: elt.group,
                color: elt.color,
                score: Number(elt.score),
                number: elt.number,
                totalPoints: elt.number * Number(elt.score)
            });
        });


        var resultArray = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (!resultArray.hasOwnProperty(result[i].group)) {
                resultArray[result[i].group] = 0;
            }
            resultArray[result[i].group] += result[i].totalPoints;
        };
        delete resultArray.undefined;
```

I'd like a result like this : create a object in each object "shop"

```
var resultArray = [{
                id: 1,
                shop: 'shop1',
                itemGroup: {
                    fruit: 1,
                    vegetable: 2
                }
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                shop: 'shop2',
                itemGroup: {
                    fruit: 2,
                    vegetable: 2
                }
            }
        ]
```

I try this

```
var out = _(groupByShop).map(function(g, key) {
            return {
                shop: key,
                item: _(g).reduce((a, o) => a.concat(Object.values(o)), []).reduce((c, v) => ({ ...c,
                    [v]: (c[v] || 0) + 1
                }), {}),
                groupOfItems: Object.entries(_(g).reduce((a, o) => a.concat(Object.values(o)), []).reduce((c, v) => ({ ...c,
                    [v]: (c[v] || 0) + 1
                }), {})).map(([item, total]) => ({
                    item,
                    total
                }))
    };
        });
```

Comment: In the `resultArray`, where do the `id`s and `itemGroup`s come from? How do they correspond to the original objects, in plain language?

Comment: shop1 seems to have 2 distinct fruits?

Comment: Id is the index and itemGroup is a new object which include the fruits and vegetables. And all the shops can have distinct fruits or vegetables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if I understand the multiplication part, but seems to match the result:

```js
var myArray = [ { shop1: "shop1", item1: "my apple 0", itemA: "my carrot 1" }, 
                { shop2: "shop1", item2: "my apple 0", itemB: "my carrot 1" }, 
                { shop3: "shop1", item3: "my apple 1", itemC: "my carrot 0" },
                { shop4: "shop2", item4: "my apple 1", itemD: "my carrot 1" }, 
                { shop5: "shop2", item5: "my apple 1", itemE: "my carrot 0" }, 
                { shop6: "shop2", item6: "my apple 0", itemF: "my carrot 1" } ];

var MyArrayDefinition = [ 
  { item: "my apple 0" , color: "red"   , group: "fruit"    , score: 0 }, 
  { item: "my carrot 1", color: "orange", group: "vegetable", score: 1 }, 
  { item: "my apple 1" , color: "red"   , group: "fruit"    , score: 1 }, 
  { item: "my carrot 0", color: "orange", group: "vegetable", score: 0 } ];

var k = Object.keys, items = MyArrayDefinition.reduce((o, v) => (o[v.item] = v, o), {}); 

var shops = myArray.reduce((o, v, i, s) => (
  s = v[k(v).find(k => k.includes('shop'))], 
  s = o[s] || (o[s] = { fruit: 0, vegetable: 0 }), 
  k(v).forEach(k => k.includes('item') && 
    (s[(i = items[v[k]]).group] += i.score) ), o), {}); 

var result = k(shops).map((k, i) => ({ id: i + 1, shop: k, itemGroup: shops[k] })); 

console.log( JSON.stringify( shops  ).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') );
console.log( JSON.stringify( result ).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') );
```

Comment: item1 or item2 are variables. there are item3, item4, etc. How to loop them ?

Comment: @observatoire by any chance do you get `myArray` from `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. I parse a csv with dsv and there is a lot of items (item1A, item1B, item2A,...etc)

Comment: Thanks Slai ! last problem for me. You loop "shop" but the value can be "shop1", "shop2", "bigshop", "smallshop"

Comment: @observatoire there are too many changes, so now it's even more confusing :]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your desired output is correct if you want the sum unique fruits of every store since your example result seems to be wrong.

You can try the following and see if it fits your purpose, console log some of the other variables (logging it here will make it too lengthy).

```js
const myArray = [{"shop":"shop1","item1":"my apple 0","item2":"my carrot 1"},{"shop":"shop1","item1":"my apple 0","item2":"my carrot 1"},{"shop":"shop1","item1":"my apple 1","item2":"my carrot 0"},{"shop":"shop2","item1":"my apple 1","item2":"my carrot 1"},{"shop":"shop2","item1":"my apple 1","item2":"my carrot 0"},{"shop":"shop2","item1":"my apple 0","item2":"my carrot 1"}];

const MyArrayDefinition = [{"item":"my apple 0","color":"red","group":"fruit","score":0},{"item":"my carrot 1","color":"orange","group":"vegetable","score":1},{"item":"my apple 1","color":"red","group":"fruit","score":1},{"item":"my carrot 0","color":"orange","group":"vegetable","score":0}];

const shopArticle = myArray.reduce(
  (result,record)=>{
    result[record.shop]=result[record.shop] || [];
    result[record.shop] = result[record.shop].concat(
      Object.keys(record).filter(key=>key.startsWith("item")).reduce(
        (r,key)=>r.concat(record[key]),
        []
      ),
      []
    );
    return result;
  },
  {}
);
const groups = MyArrayDefinition.reduce(
  (result,{item,group,score})=>{
    result[item] = {group,score};
    return result;
  },
  {}
)
console.log(
  Object.keys(shopArticle)
  .sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b))
  .map(
    (key,id)=>({id:id+1,shop:key,itemGroup:shopArticle[key].reduce(
      (result,key)=>{
        result[groups[key].group] += groups[key].score;
        return result;
      },
      {fruit:0,vegetable:0}
    )})
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks but the result I'd like is : shop 1 > fruit=1, vegetable=2 and shop 2 > fruit=2, vegetable=2. I' d like to calculate the result using "score" somewhere (total of each unique fruit or vegetable * their score)

Comment: in the result, the value for "fruit" and "vegetable" is not the sum of each, the result is the total of points (sum of each fruit or vegetable * score of each)

Comment: @observatoire updated answer, total score for each shop each group, assuming fruit and vegetable, if you have more groups then you have to reduce `MyArrayDefinition` to an object with group as key and 0 as value.